# Mixing two signals in a GainNode in web audio api

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I am building an audio mixer using Web Audio API. Currently, my mixer has two channels that play an AudioSourceBufferNode and are mixed by connecting both sources to the same GainNode so the samples are summed together. When the channels are playing the same audio file / song I see that the output is clipping which makes sense as I guess the resulting sample exceeds the bit depth or available dynamic range.

I am attaching an image of the clipping when the two channels are playing and when just one channel is playing.

[image]

What should I do so I get the same audio signal if I play the song on one channel or if I play that song on both channels? (i.e. preventing clipping without modifying the audio)

Comment: You will probably want to duck the sources by `-3dB` (i.e multiply each source by `0.707`) to give equal power. The only guaranteed way to avoid clipping with 2 normalised sources is to multiple by `0.5` (approx. `-6dB`) though this means some parts of the combined audio sources may be perceived as quieter compared to when they are played individually.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557005/mixing-two-audio-buffers-put-one-on-background-of-another-by-using-web-audio-ap